# AudioToolbox decreases sound volume when app starts

Tags: iphone, ios, volume, audiotoolbox

In my app I use the AudioToolbox framework so that I can use the iSpeech SDK. If music is playing (in the background, from the Apple music app), when the app starts, the music skips (stops playing completely) for just a moment (half a second), then resumes at a diminished volume. I'm not at all sure why this is happening, but Google had nothing to say about it. Has anyone experienced a problem like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Audio needs to insert a mixer in the audio output path so that your app has a way to make sounds.  (Think of the "skip" as pulling out and plugging in patch cords.)  The mixer allocates some volume to your app; what's left for the music player is less than 100%, thus the disminished volume.

Comment: Interesting; that actually makes a lot of sense. Are you saying there is not a work-around?